# Fingerprint without popup view

Tags: ios, touch-id

I wonder if it's possible to scan the fingerprint without show a popup view of LAContext

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. It would be a security concern.
In more details, it is controlled by the system, your app just request it to authenticate the user

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if there is no another answer I will accept it.

Comment: @ZakiAlKaram There is no possible other answer. `LAContext` is the *only* possible way to use Touch ID.

Comment: I had the same problem because I wanted to build an auth screen like iOS has and I wanted without that promp because it doesn't look that good. :) But I had to accept it

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your help